# Correct management of php session for redirection

Tags: php, session

In my PHP application, I heavily use sessions to save information during redirection:

- Saving information on category, so the correct tab and/or form is displayed after a redirection
- Saving information when you are logged in to access some functionalities
- Saving information on errors and warnings so they are displayed once all back-end operations are done and you are redirected to the main dashboard

In implementing that I called session_start in about 40 scripts, but outside of occasionally calling `unset()` on a `$_SESSION` variable I don't close the session in any way.

Now, while I was investigating performance issues on my server, it came to my attention that [an underuse of `session_write_close()` might be the issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/849705/apache-unresponsive-stalling-occasionally) (even if the question was on an apache linux and my web app is hosted on a wamp server) and that in the end, even if it is not the cause, it might be sensible to try to close the session as soon and as often as I can.

I'm wondering how do I identify the points where I can safely destroy/restart the session? And what would be the best way to do that?

Keep in mind I want the number of opened session not being an issue, so I want to be sure to keep it at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we do not close session unless it is very important since session would be closed as soon as browser is closed.
Due to lack of knowledge of your application we are not in position to comment on exact need to close session in script. Considering the events you described it might be better idea to use cookies in certain situation like  "Saving information when you are logged in to access some functionalities". Regarding error and warnings; you may like to remove some session variables after you have displayed messages on dashboard page.

For "Saving information on category, so the correct tab and/or form is displayed after a redirection" you can consider using parameters in URL to show desired tabs instead of using session variable.

In case you plan to use session_write_close() then in that case you would need to do session_start if you need access to session in the same script a second time. Use of session_write_close() is only to resolve locking of session in case two scripts try to access same session at same time. So you may like to describe if it is the case with your application or not.

Comment: I'm willing to give more details, as soon as I figure out where to begin... But to be honest it is quite a tricky situation and I'm not even 100% sure that sessions are the issue there. Is there a way to track session usage? Like how many sessions are open at one point and how long a session is opened? Or maybe I should abandon this line of investigation altogether...